# Is it possible to filter a SQLite query so that each value appears only once in each column

Tags: sqlite

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable

a  | b
---+----
1  | 2 
2  | 10 
2  | 5 
3  | 10
```

I want each number to only appear once in each column, i.e. the result should be:

```
a  | b
---+----
1  | 2 
2  | 10
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to add a column with ID. Then do this:

```
select a, b from mytable m1 where
a not in (select m2.a from mytable m2 where m2.id < m1.id)
and
b not in (select m3.b from mytable m3 where m3.id < m1.id)
```

If you don't want to decide by the order of IDs, you can add another column (like a sequence).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However, my example was correct - I do not want any repeated element in any column.  I do want to filter out (3, 10) since (2, 10) already exists.

Comment: Ah - I was hoping there would be an easier way.  Thanks for the answer.